# How to use IN/NOT IN operators with wildcards in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to check if a variable's value is LIKE few other values (similar to SQL's LIKE operator).  For example, I was hoping the below would print `valid`.  But it doesn't.  Are wildcards allowed in the list of values being compared?

```
declare @var nvarchar(50) = 'SPARK'

IF (UPPER(TRIM(@var)) NOT IN ('%SQL%', '%SERVER%', '%PAR%'))
    print('invalid')
else
    print('valid')
```

Comment: I think the title is misguiding: you want to use `IN`/`NOT IN` with wildcards, not `LIKE`.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Very valid point.  Corrected it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in an `IN` clause. `NOT IN ('%SQL%', '%SERVER%', '%PAR%')` would check if the value is *literally* one of those values, so your value `'SPARK'` would not match the last value, `'%PAR%'`. Effectively a `NOT IN` is parsed in the background like so:

```sql
@VAR != '%SQL%' AND @VAR != '%SERVER%' AND @VAR != '%PAR%'
```

*This is why `NULL` values give "unexpected" results in a `NOT IN`, as `!= NULL` results in UNKNOWN, and thus the clause resolves to UNKNOWN, which* not *TRUE.*

One work around, however, is to use an `EXISTS` (or in this case, a `NOT EXISTS`):

```sql
DECLARE @var nvarchar(50) = N'SPARK';

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(N'SQL'),(N'SERVER'),(N'PAR'))V(S) WHERE @VAR LIKE CONCAT(N'%',V.S,N'%'))
    PRINT('invalid');
ELSE
    PRINT('valid');
```